# Как с помощью Robot эмулировать геймпад в Java?

Tags: java

С помощью java.awt.Robot можно эмулировать нажатия мыши и клавиатуры, но как эмулировать нажатия геймпада(Robot был приведен, как пример. Любая библиотека подойдет)? Помогите, пожалуйста.

Comment: Вопрос доконца не понятен... Могли бы уточнить что такое Robot?

Comment: @antonio112009 класс java.awt.Robot из стандартной библиотеки